# section tag jquery hide show effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm having trouble getting the sections to show, I'm terribly stuck and no longer know what I'm doing wrong. The last change that I made, that made the sections to stop showing when they used to work with jquery, is I coded a jquery menu into the menu section. I successfully coded the jquery menu and later found out that when I clicked the link, the menu did not hide and show the new section. I fiddled with it thinking it was just the javascript order but I changed it to different orders and the problem persisted. I don't know what you would need to know to find out what the problem is but I'll just put the essentials here.

This is the website I'm working on, in the menu, only the first link is coded for jquery the rest are just hashtags.

```
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=euc-jp">

<title>Universal Magazine</title>
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/templatemo_main.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.fancybox.css">
<!--<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cutive' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/templatemo_misc.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/menu.css">

</head>

<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    <a href="#coupons" class="change-section hovers">
        <div class="fixed-btn visible-md visible-lg">
            <div class="coupons"> 
<!-- this is a button that i coded to the menu-->
                <div class="image">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#coupons" class="change-section">
        <div class="photo visible-xs visible-sm">
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
</body>
est compiled and minified JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->
    <script src="js/jquery.backstretch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/menu.js"></script>
    <script src="js/templatemo_script.js"></script>
<!--templatemo_script.js file contents:-->
<script>
    /* 
Zoom Template 
http://www.templatemo.com/preview/templatemo_414_zoom
*/

var menuDisabled = false;

jQuery(function($) {

    $(window).load(function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded
            $('#status').fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation
            $('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow'); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website.
            $('#main-wrapper').delay(350).css({'overflow':'visible'});
    });

    $(document).ready( function() {

        loadGoogleMap();

        // backstretch for background image
        var defaultImgSrc = $('img.main-img').attr('src');
        $.backstretch(defaultImgSrc, {speed: 400});

    //for image slide on menu item click(normal) and responsive
    $(".change-section").on('click',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            if (menuDisabled == false) // check the menu has disabled?
            {
                menuDisabled = true; // disable to menu

                var name = $(this).attr('href');
                console.log(name);
                // get image url and assign to backstretch for background
                var imgSrc = $("img"+name+"-img").attr('src');
                $.backstretch(imgSrc, {speed: 400}); //backstretch for background fade in/out

                // content zoom in/out
                $("section.active").hide('size',{easing: 'easeInQuart', duration: 400},function(){
                    $(this).removeClass("active");
                    $(name+"-section").show('size',{easing: 'easeOutQuart', duration: 400},function(){
                        $(this).addClass("active");

                        // google map need to resize for animate contents
                        google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); // resize map
                        $.backstretch("resize"); // resize the background image
                        menuDisabled = false;
                     });
                });                
            }
            return;
    });

    });

});

var map = '';

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
      zoom: 14,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(16.8496189,96.1288854)
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),  mapOptions);
}

function loadGoogleMap(){
    // load google map
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&' +
        'callback=initialize';
    document.body.appendChild(script);
}
</script>
<!--jquery menu settings-->
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            /**
            * for each menu element, on mouseenter, 
            * we enlarge the image, and show both sdt_active span and 
            * sdt_wrap span. If the element has a sub menu (sdt_box),
            * then we slide it - if the element is the last one in the menu
            * we slide it to the left, otherwise to the right
            */
            $('#sdt_menu > li').bind('mouseenter',function(){
                var $elem = $(this);
                $elem.find('img')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({
                        'width':'170px',
                        'height':'170px',
                        'left':'0px'
                     },400,'easeOutBack')
                     .andSelf()
                     .find('.sdt_wrap')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'top':'140px'},500,'easeOutBack')
                     .andSelf()
                     .find('.sdt_active')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'height':'170px'},300,function(){
                    var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
                    if($sub_menu.length){
                        var left = '170px';
                        if($elem.parent().children().length == $elem.index()+1)
                            left = '-170px';
                        $sub_menu.show().animate({'left':left},200);
                    }   
                });
            }).bind('mouseleave',function(){
                var $elem = $(this);
                var $sub_menu = $elem.find('.sdt_box');
                if($sub_menu.length)
                    $sub_menu.hide().css('left','0px');

                $elem.find('.sdt_active')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'height':'0px'},300)
                     .andSelf().find('img')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({
                        'width':'0px',
                        'height':'0px',
                        'left':'85px'},400)
                     .andSelf()
                     .find('.sdt_wrap')
                     .stop(true)
                     .animate({'top':'25px'},500);
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: whats the error? or required ?

Comment: could you create a jsfiddle, http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: ill try to create a fiddle, i tried before but i just couldnt get it working, ill try anyways, ill link you to the actual website (http://www.universalmagazine.net) so you can see how the link isnt working, hopefully i can get a straight answer from that, meanwhile ill do the jsfiddle asap.